# Hide null members in Visual Studio watch window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How can I hide null members in watch screen? I don't need that.

Below is an screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work that way.  The inspector is there for you to see *all available members*.  The visibility of the members never has anything to do with the *value* of the member, null or otherwise.  Conceivably you might be able to write a plugin that replaces the inspector in its entirety, to do what you want, but that would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the ToString on the class to display something that's useful to you. If you don't want to that your best bet might be to use the `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` attribute to create a DebuggerToString that can be used in the debugger. Have a look at this [(MSDN) Enhancing Debugging with the Debugger Display Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992.aspx) or [(blog) Why override ToString()? Use DebuggerDisplayAttribute instead](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/soultech/archive/2011/04/05/whyoverridetostring_2d00_use_2d00_debuggerdisplayattribute_2d00_instead.aspx)

You would do this at the class level on your GDicStruct rather than on the properties.

So you could add

```
[DebuggerDisplayAttribute("{DebuggerToString}")]
public struct GDicStruct
{
    public string DebuggerToString()
    {
        //logic to create debugger string
    }
}
```

but you have to ask if it's worth the effort.